# matlab2tikz ignoring error bars

Tags: pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I'm using `matlab2tikz` for a plot with horizontal error bars, but the `pgfplots` file generated doesn't include the error bars, while everything else is fine. I'm plotting my data in matlab like this:

```
y = [604.40,599.84,602.23,616.96,582.62,575.40,570.14,572.77,574.53];
x =  [4.05  ,4.05  ,4.05  ,4.05  ,4.20  ,4.37  ,4.55  ,4.55  ,4.37  ];
ebars =  [0.0563,0.0563,0.0326,0.0326,0.0350,0.0254,0.0437,0.0437,0.0254];
figure(1)
clf
errorbar(x,y,2*ebars,'horizontal','o')
legend('s1');
```

Which gives me this:

[image: Original matlab plot]

When I then run matlab2tikz, the resulting file is:

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=3.358in,
height=2.309in,
at={(0.563in,0.312in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=3.8,
xmax=4.8,
ymin=570,
ymax=620,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, draw=none, mark=o, mark options={solid, mycolor1}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
4.05    604.4\\
4.05    599.84\\
4.05    602.23\\
4.05    616.96\\
4.2 582.62\\
4.37    575.4\\
4.55    570.14\\
4.55    572.77\\
4.37    574.53\\
};
\addlegendentry{s1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Which gives me this:
[image: pgfplots plot]

What might be stopping my error bars carrying over?

Answer (score 1):

Support for horizontal error bars was added to Matlab in version 2016b as I understand it (based on https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99308-how-can-i-create-horizontal-error-bars-in-matlab?). But looking at the `matlab2tikz` code, it appears there is only support for vertical error bars.

I don't have Matlab 2016b or newer here, but in 2015b it works as expected with vertical errorbars.

Hence, what's stopping the error bars is likely that they're not implemented in `matlab2tikz`. Post a feature request at https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/issues

---

Addendum: JMJ reported this at https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/issues/1016

Comment: Thanks, I've posted a feature request, will update if there's anything helpful